# using "or" in pattern matching regular expression

Tags: regex

I am using a regular expression to find the matched pattern. But somehow I am not able to find all Occrences.

My input file from where I need to match the pattern(please note that this is an example file with only 3 occurrence, in real - it have multiple Occrences) :

```
aaa-233- hi, how are you? 
aaa-234- 6(-8989) 
aaa-235- 123
end
```

So, I want my output to be

```
 hi, how are you? 
 6(-8988) 
 123
```

My regex is

```
aaa\\-[A-Za-z0-9,->#]\\-(.+?)(aaa)
```

Pseudo code

```
Output= matcher.group(2);
```

How can I make the logic to start read from aaa and end either it encounters aaa or end.

Comment: Maybe use [`(?m)^aaa-\s*(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/iNzFYP/1) and grab Group 1?

Comment: Not sure if you're also trying to match `\n` (if content after `aaa` and before `aaa` or `end` may include newline chars). If that's the case, you can use `(?ms)(?<=^aaa- )(?:(?!^(?:aaa|end$)).)+` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/1D88vx/1)

Comment: I just updated my question. Basically, I need to find data between aaa-233-  and next time it encounters aaa. It should go on until it finds end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(?sm)^aaa-[^-]+-.*?(?=\naaa|\nend|\z)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/j5QgCO/2)

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?ms)                    set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (with .
                           matching \n) (case-sensitive) (matching
                           whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  aaa-                     'aaa-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^-]+                    any character except: '-' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    aaa                      'aaa'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    end                      'end'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \z                       the end of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```